# showing $\frac{d}{dt} tr(F_t^m) = m \phantom{1} d [ tr(\eta \wedge F_t^{m-1})]$

Tags: differential-forms

This problem is exactly same problem in Chern-Weil Theorem. Here I focus simplest examples, say trace without considering the shape of $P_m(F_1, F_2, \cdots, F_m)$.

Let $A_t = A_0 + t\eta$, $F_0 = dA_0 + A_0 \wedge A_0$, $F_t = dA_t + A_t \wedge A_t $
Decompose $F_t$ into $F_0$ I have 
\begin{align}
F_t
= F_0 + t(d\eta + A_0 \wedge \eta + \eta \wedge A_0) + t^2 \eta \wedge \eta
\end{align}

Now consider $ tr(F_t^m)$.

What I want to prove is following

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} tr(F_t^m) = m \phantom{1} d [ tr(\eta \wedge F_t^{m-1})] 
\end{align}
Let's call this equation (*)

---

Followings are my trial 
\begin{align}
  \frac{d}{dt} tr(F_t^m) &= m \phantom{1} tr\left(\frac{\partial F_t}{\partial t}  
  F_t^{m-1}\right)  \\
  & = m \phantom{1} tr\left(  (d\eta + A_0\wedge \eta + \eta \wedge A_0)  \wedge F_t^{m-1}\right) + 2 m t \phantom{1} tr\left(\eta \wedge \eta \wedge F_t^{m-1}\right)   
\end{align}

Now 
\begin{align}
md \phantom{1} tr(\eta \wedge F_t^{m-1}) = mtr(d\eta \wedge F_t^{m-1}) - m(m-1) tr(\eta \wedge d F_t \wedge F_t^{m-2})
\end{align}
Using bianchi identity $dF_t + [A_t, F_t]=0$, I can replace the last term into $-[A_t, F_t]$, but still I have no idea that R.H.S and L.H.S are same in equation (*)

Comment: what is $P_m(F_1,...,F_m)$?

Comment: @janmarqz, $P_m(F_1, \cdots, F_m)$ is a symmetric invariant polynomial of degree $m$. Simply if all $F_i=F$, then I can just set $P_m(F) = tr(F^m)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this $A, F$ are Lie algebra valued differential forms. Note for $p$, $q$ differential forms we have 
\begin{align}
w_p \wedge w_q = (-1)^{pq} w_q \wedge w_p
\end{align}
But for Lie algebra valued $p$, $q$ forms 
\begin{align}
A_p \wedge A_q = (-1)^{pq +1} A_q \wedge A_p
\end{align}

using this I have
\begin{align}
  &tr(\eta \wedge \eta \wedge F_t^{m-1}) = - tr(\eta \wedge F_t^{m-1} \wedge \eta)=0 \\
  & tr(\eta \wedge A_0 \wedge F_t^{m-1}) = tr(A_0 \wedge \eta \wedge F_t^{m-1}) = - tr(A_0 \wedge F_t^{m-1} \wedge \eta)=0
\end{align}
and this guarantee the equation (*).